# (Spring 4.3.3-Hibernate 5.1.5)Unable to create sessionFactory object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am new to `Hibernate` and I am trying to integrate `Spring 4.3.3` with `Hibernate 5.1.5`.

I am getting the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'loginservice'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'loginServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'loginDAO'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'loginDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'hibernateTemplate'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/db-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'sessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/db-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get
>   constructor for
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

My DB config file:
[db-config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R9ZY.png)

Could someone please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide us your code?

Comment: googling HibernateTemplate it seems it should no longer be used.